# How do I create a hotkey for compound actions in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-15, intellij-idea-2016

Is it possible to create a script of multiple actions/tasks in IntelliJ IDEA and trigger them with a single hotkey/abbreviation?

I want to periodically do:

```
1 Reimport all maven projects
2 Build -> Rebuild Project
3 Run Application
```

Can I trigger these 3 actions with a single hotkey/abbreviation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want [macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html), under Edit -> Macros.

Once you've recorded a macro you can bind a shortcut to it in keymap settings.

Comment: Dam bro! That was fast. Great answer!

Comment: @user674669 could you please [mark the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that it shows as solved? Thanks!